Ribbon fusion categories for quantum $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ at odd roots of unity
I will work over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $q=e^{2\pi i/N}$, and write $U_{q}(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ for Lusztig's divided power quantum group for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.
One can associate to $U_{q}(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ a ribbon fusion category $\mathrm{Ver}_N$ by taking the semisimplification of the category of tilting modules for $U_{q}(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$.
If $N$ is even (and $N\geq 2$), it is well-known that $\mathrm{Ver}_N$ is a modular tensor category, and its modular data can be found in many references (for instance the textbook authored by Bakalov and Kirillov).
On the other hand, if $N$ is odd (and $N\geq 3$), it appears to be known to experts that $\mathrm{Ver}_N$ is not modular: I have read that its Müger center is $\mathrm{sVec}$. However, I have struggled to find a reference for this fact in the literature. I would also be interested to know what the "modular" data for $\mathrm{Ver}_N$ is in this case. What are some comprehensive references for $\mathrm{Ver}_N$?
